# Add text to Tezos contract storage results in HttpRequestFailed: Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded

Tags: taquito, storage

I'm trying to get [this tutorial](https://blog.openreplay.com/creating-a-blockchain-decentralized-app-with-vue-and-tezos) to work but adding a memo to the Tezos blockchain always results in a **HttpRequestFailed: Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded**

Full repo:
https://github.com/MelvinManni/tez_memo

Code:

```
    /**
   * @param {string} memo
   * @description Creates a new memo and adds it to the contract storage
   */
  async addMemo({ dispatch }, memo) {
    try {
      const contract = await getContract();
      const op = await contract.methods.addMemo(memo).send();
      await op.confirmation()
      dispatch("softUpdateMemoList");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
```

Any ideas on how to fix this are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these [lines](https://github.com/MelvinManni/tez_memo/blob/f00b157c470466831d50a072b6072149b836b366/src/store/actions.js#L8):

```
const network = { type: NetworkType.ITHACANET };

// initialiize the SDK
const Tezos = new TezosToolkit("https://ithacanet.ecadinfra.com");
```

To:

```
const network = { type: NetworkType.GHOSTNET };

// initialiize the SDK
const Tezos = new TezosToolkit("https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz");
```

`ithacanet` was renamed to `ghostnet`, and is now a long running test network.